# Firefox protected mode and as3 flash player microphone bug?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, firefox, microphone, protected-mode

I am building a cam publishing client in as3 for flash. It's almost finished, but I encountered some weird problem. In all browsers it works like a charm, but I discovered after two days of debugging that the "protected mode" of Firefox crashes the application.

The problem is as follows. I have two dropdowns. One for the camera and one for the microphone. When I change the camera, it selects it and shows a preview. I can do this as many times as I like. It's different with the microphone dropdown. After two selects it crashes the app. The activityLevel indicator isn't also working as expected. While in the other browsers it's ok.

I discovered that when I turn off protected mode it works ok. Now I want to let the application also run in protected mode, because this is the default behavior.

I can't find the problem. My code is as follows for the microphone.

The application is build with flex and compiled with mxmlc.

When I set setLoopBack to false, the application doesn't crash, but the activityLevel isn't triggered and the sound isn't working. I use a similar approach for the selection of the camera and this one is working pretty well.

Are there some special limitations to protected mode in Firefox? I can't find one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found it. Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone() did the trick.